# Collision Detection

Tags: python, scripting, collision

So i found a script for an Collision Detection @ https://www.cbcity.de/simple-3d-collision-detection-with-python-scripting-in-blender
But it seems outdated as i get some Errors , any ideas on how to make this run again?

Comment: so if i want to check the collision between two pointclouds is there an easy way to assign multiple objects with bounding boxes?

Comment: The script does just work for 2 cubes. I don’t think that there is an easy way - but there might be built-in functions which can do that. I know there is such a functionality in UPBGE - so you can easily detect collisions between objects - but I don’t whether vanilla Blender has this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
 
def get_BoundBox(object_name):
    """
    returns the corners of the bounding box of an object in world coordinates
    #  ________ 
    # |\       |\
    # |_\______|_\
    # \ |      \ |
    #  \|_______\|
    # 
    """
    
    ob = bpy.context.scene.objects[object_name]
    bbox_corners = [ob.matrix_world @ Vector(corner) for corner in ob.bound_box]
 
    return bbox_corners
 
 
 
def check_Collision(box1, box2):
    """
    Check Collision of 2 Bounding Boxes
    box1 & box2 muss Liste mit Vector sein,
    welche die Eckpunkte der Bounding Box
    enthält
    #  ________ 
    # |\       |\
    # |_\______|_\
    # \ |      \ |
    #  \|_______\|
    # 
    #
    """
    print('\nKollisionscheck mit:')
 
    x_max = max([e[0] for e in box1])
    x_min = min([e[0] for e in box1])
    y_max = max([e[1] for e in box1])
    y_min = min([e[1] for e in box1])
    z_max = max([e[2] for e in box1])
    z_min = min([e[2] for e in box1])
    print('Box1 min %.2f, %.2f, %.2f' % (x_min, y_min, z_min))
    print('Box1 max %.2f, %.2f, %.2f' % (x_max, y_max, z_max))    
     
    x_max2 = max([e[0] for e in box2])
    x_min2 = min([e[0] for e in box2])
    y_max2 = max([e[1] for e in box2])
    y_min2 = min([e[1] for e in box2])
    z_max2 = max([e[2] for e in box2])
    z_min2 = min([e[2] for e in box2])
    print('Box2 min %.2f, %.2f, %.2f' % (x_min2, y_min2, z_min2))
    print('Box2 max %.2f, %.2f, %.2f' % (x_max2, y_max2, z_max2))        
     
     
    isColliding = ((x_max >= x_min2 and x_max <= x_max2) \
                    or (x_min <= x_max2 and x_min >= x_min2)) \
                    and ((y_max >= y_min2 and y_max <= y_max2) \
                    or (y_min <= y_max2 and y_min >= y_min2)) \
                    and ((z_max >= z_min2 and z_max <= z_max2) \
                    or (z_min <= z_max2 and z_min >= z_min2))
 
    if isColliding:
        print('Kollision!')
         
    return isColliding
 
# MAIN
# Check Collision of Objects named 'Cube1' and 'Cube2' in Scene
collision = check_Collision(get_BoundBox('Cube1'), get_BoundBox('Cube2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This creates bounding boxes from objects and then returns True if the bounding boxes are touching using the [BVHTree overlap](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.overlap) method. Otherwise, it'll return False.

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree

def worldBoundingBox(obj):
    """returns the corners of the bounding box of an object in world coordinates"""
    return [obj.matrix_world @ Vector(corner) for corner in obj.bound_box]

def objectsOverlap(obj1, obj2):
    """returns True if the object's bounding boxes are overlapping"""
    vert1 = worldBoundingBox(obj1)
    vert2 = worldBoundingBox(obj2)
    faces = [(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 7, 6, 5), (0, 4, 5, 1), (1, 5, 6, 2), (2, 6, 7, 3), (4, 0, 3, 7)]

    bvh1 = BVHTree.FromPolygons(vert1, faces)
    bvh2 = BVHTree.FromPolygons(vert2, faces)

    return bool(bvh1.overlap(bvh2))
```